# Disable sound and vibration for Gmail Notifications

Tags: notifications, gmail

I want to switch off sound and vibration alerts for Gmail, but leave on the icon (in the notification bar). I still want it to vibrate on Google Hangouts and Facebook Messenger notification, etc.

I'm using Android 4.4.2

Comment: Are you trying to turn off Gmail notifications completely, or do you want it to still make a sound but not vibrate?

Comment: I still want to see the mail icon in the bar at top, but no sound or vibrate, but I want facebook/messanger/google hangouts to sound and vibrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android notification settings can be configured on a per-app basis.  Most apps give you control over sound and vibration settings.  These can be overridden with the global "Ring mode" setting located under Menu -> System -> Sound.

Changing the Gmail notifications will not impact Hangouts, Facebook, or other apps.  Furthermore, in Gmail app you can have different notification settings for each account (and even per each synced label within each account):

1. In Gmail, tap on the Menu button, go to Settings, and tap on your Google account.
   [image] [image]
2. Tap on "Inbox sound & vibrate" option.
   [image]
3. Set the sound and vibration preferences to your liking, and exit the Settings page.
   [image]