# Disable Notification Vibration for Specific Apps

Tags: settings, notifications, 5.1-lollipop, vibration

I would like to change a setting for my Android (v5.1.1) to make my YouTube app show notifications (on the Lock Screen and Status Bar as it currently does), but without vibration and sound.  That is, I want to override the default notification volume/vibrate settings.

Looking at other Android StackExchange questions such as [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69611/disable-sound-and-vibration-for-gmail-notifications), it appears that this might be a feature I would need to rely on the developers of the app to implement.  Assuming this is not the case, is there is any setting that would allow app notifications while disabling the volume/vibrate only for that app?

Answer (score 3):

Via https://www.xda-developers.com/stop-vibrations-android-apps/ :

Vibration can be disabled per-app with an [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) command:

```
adb shell
cmd appops set [package] VIBRATE ignore
```

The [package] is usually something like "com.somecompany.someappname". There are a various programs that will let you see the name of apps (the page there suggests one), but

```
adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
```

should do it as well.

More detailed info about installing and using adb is listed at the top link or in other answers on SE.

Comment: Seriously, this is the only way?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: If there is another way, I don't know of it. I agree that it seems excessive for this to be necessary; the ability could easily have been made revokable via GUI in Android's per-app "App info" settings, just as various app permissions can be slid to "off" and "Manage app notifications>Block all" can be set to "On", but it is what it is.