# How to list all apps with a specific permission in ADB?

Tags: adb, permissions

I want to list all apps with a specific permission.
For instance, output the package names of  apps with the `VIBRATE` permission. The apps with a specific permission then be revoked or enabled [as instructed here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120213/disable-notification-vibration-for-specific-apps).

`adb shell 'pm list packages -e'` outputs all packages.

Comment: See if my answer is still useful: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/129474/96277 or this one: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123100/96277

Comment: @Firelord I will eventually. I'm very sure that I've used a one-liner command to achieve this in the past (likely saw in a now-deleted Reddit post).

Comment: Looks like [there's a one-liner on another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/188486/44325), but it may have a caveat.

Comment: ...I've used the command `adb shell cmd appops set`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
`adb shell cmd appops query-op PERMISSION`
For example:
`adb shell cmd appops query-op READ_CONTACTS`